# Meteor+Angular: ng-repeat doesn't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

(This is not one of those "Oh I forgot `$scope.$apply()`" problems)

Question is: How to get a `ng-repeat` live binding with a reactive helper function in the controller to work?

Code says more than thousand words (I've stripped everything unnecessary):

**index.js:**

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
    <!-- (...) -->

    <div class="dashboard" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl as ctrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="timer in app.timers">
            <li>{{timer.entry.title}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**AppCtrl.js:**

```
angular.module('spectroscope').controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$reactive', '$interval',
function($scope, $reactive, $interval) {
  var me = this;

  // Make this reactive
  $reactive(this).attach($scope);

  me._timers = {};

  $.each(Entry.find().fetch(), function(idx, entry) {
    me._timers[entry._id] = new Timer(entry, $interval);
  });


  /**
   * Logic for creating a new entry
   */
  me.createEntry = function() {
    let entry = new Entry(),
        titleField = me.addEntryContainer.find('input[name=title]');


    // Create new entry
    entry.title = titleField.val();
    entry.save();


    // Create a new timer
    let timer = new Timer(entry, $interval);
    me._timers[entry._id] = timer;
  };



  // Reactive helpers
  this.helpers({
    /**
     * Returns all timer objects
     */
    timers: function() {
      let timers = [];

      $.each(me._timers,  function(id, timer) {
        timers.push(timer);
      });

      return timers;
    }
  });
}]);
```

Everything works fine: There's more code for start and stop the timers of the time tracking app and display the time spent per entry etc and if timers are running, the (not in the code above visible) time elements in the `<li>`s are updated.

The problem: If I add a new timer/entry (`AppCtrl.createEntry()`), the new created timer doesn't show up in the list. The helper function just will not be called again by `ng-repeat`.

A `$scope.$apply()` call doesn't work since a `$apply` is already in process as this point due the method is called by a `ng-submit` directive.

I've also tried to replace the `_timer` field with a `ReactiveVar` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: You are creating new objects instead of linking angular to you meteor collection. If you need to use new Timer you also need a watcher that rebuild the array when the collection changes

Comment: (`Entry` is a Astronomy model here). That could be. But how am I actually doing that? In my opinion it shouldn't be required to interact with collections when using astronomy.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell 100% from your code what's going on, but it looks like you are not pulling your `timers` from a Meteor minimongo collection.  Helpers are supposed to help you get data out of minimongo, and not much else.  If you aren't using a minimongo collection, just use me.timers in your template instead of a helper that creates another array. If you are using a minimongo collection, you probably need to actually include a minimongo command, such as `return Timers.find({})`.